# How do I solve this matrix?

Tags: matrices, matrix-equations

How do I expand the following matrix?  I have no experience in linear algebra (well 35 years ago..)

Its the equation just after equation 16b in [this link](http://www.qsl.net/ik1xpv/dsp/aiqben.htm)

---

Here are the equations in question:

$$
        \begin{bmatrix}
        Y_m(n) \\
        {Y^*}_{-m}(n) \\
        \end{bmatrix}
= {K_m}^{-1}$$

$$
        \begin{bmatrix}
        Z_m(n) \\
        {Z^*}_{-m}(n) \\
        \end{bmatrix}
=  {K_m}^{-1}{K}_m\begin{bmatrix}
        Y_m(n) \\
        {Y^*}_{-m}(n) \\
        \end{bmatrix}
$$

Where
$$
K_m = 
\begin{bmatrix}
K_{1m} & K_{2m}\\
K_{2m}^* & K_{1m}^*
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Comment: I have added the equations for you.

Comment: Here is an excellent reference, by the way, for learning how to typeset these kinds of things: [MathJax basic tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: @DietrichBurde [there are many Toms](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2860405/tom) in this world

Comment: Perhaps.  I think it is safe, for now, to exclude those that were non-existent, or otherwise hindered in the study of linear algebra, 35 years ago.

Comment: @Theophile thanks a lot!